# is it possible to write python scripts which can do router configuration without telnetting into the router?

Tags: python

i want to do router configuration using python , but dont want to use any application level protocol to configure it . Is it possible to deal it on a hardware level ? Please do tell if the question is vague or if it needs more explanation , then I would put more details on as to what I have my doubt in

Comment: What do you mean, "deal with it on a hardware level"? Resoldering chips inside the router? Configuring it over Ethernet? Getting out a Sharpie and handwriting Python code on its case?

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question by itself makes some sense.

The body of your question doesn't make sense.

---

`is it possible to write python scripts which can do router configuration without telnetting into the router?`

Yes, depending on the platform. You maybe able to use a variety of other methods to configure the router that do not include `telnet`. E.g. xml-rpc, ssh + interactive, scp config file or fragments, snmp to induce upload config file, etc.

---

`Is it possible to deal it on a hardware level?`

You're in the realms of nanotech microscopy and seriously invalidating the warranty on your router.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package named roscraco that configure and extract information from some consumer level routers. It's available on PyPi.